# Add CSS with PHP if statment?

Tags: php, css, if-statement

I have an if statement which shows a countdown only on Sundays and Wednesdays. But, I need to add padding to the body as well for it to display correctly.

So basically I need to add padding to the body when a line of php is executed.

Is this possible?

Comment: do you do inline css(style="") or use a css file?

Comment: What is the basic setup of your site? It's difficult to make a recommendation unless we can consider more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep your styles and HTML separate, you can add a class to the body based on the same if statement. Then use your CSS to add styles to that class:

```
<?php 
$dayOfWeek = date( "w", $timestamp);
if ($dayOfWeek == 0 || $dayOfWeek == 3) { ?>
    <body class="withCountdown">
<?php } else { ?>
    <body>
<?php } ?>

body.withCountdown {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

(Excuse my rusty PHP syntax!)

Comment: Thanks this worked! I did change the upper portion to: <?php $today = date('N'); if($today == 3 or $today == 7) { ?> which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="padding:<?php echo(is_sunday() ? '4px' : '0' );?>" >
```